# Importing QTP object repository to Excel

Tags: excel, testing, automation, qtp

I use an **excel-based automation framework** where objects' names are parameterized into the excel sheet that drives test execution.

**I need to import the QTP Object Repository to Excel/Spreadsheet in a simple readable format** so that I can write a macro to fetch the objects' logical name alone into the excel sheet.

Is this possible? If so please explain.

(I understand that **we have the option to import in XML format**, but that is not helping much.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot export the Object Repository to Excel directly.  You can only export it to XML.  If you do not find the XML format useful, you will have to determine what is useful for you.  You could take the XML file and convert it to different formats using XML Stylesheets (XSL).  You could write a script that would parse the XML nodes for the test objects and just output the names.  There are many options available once you have the data in a standard format like XML.

If you need more assistance, I suggest you post a sample of an Object Repository structure you want to export to Excel, and then post a sample of how you want that data presented in Excel.

Comment: I don't see your output.  Broken link??

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. As stated in question, I understand the "export-to-XML" feature. What I would want should be similar to the below output.   ![Valid XHTML][OR_Output][OR_Output]:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_oT1i-JbmCgbFhZWnNRU2MwaXc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: For that type of structured content in Excel, you should look at writing an Excel macro to read the exported XML content, parse the data you want, and then fill in the proper cells in the workbook.  Alternatively, you could write the XML parsing logic in your language of choice (even use VBScript in QTP if you want) and build the workbook using the Excel API.  You will find many examples on the web of how to work with XML and how to work with Excel API.

Comment: Yeah, I was also working on that lines and the link in previous comment shows output of the code I wrote in VBScript. I was just wondering if there is any ready-made utility ;-) Also have to learn how to insert images and links into comments :D

Comment: I think your implementation is specialized enough that you won't find a ready-made utility.  You'll likely find that getting this to work won't be too complicated, and then you'll have the power to tweak it to meet changing future needs as well.  Good luck!